# as.Date() changing the values of dates to NA

Tags: r, date, format, lubridate, as.date

I am trying to change these dates from character to dates using the as.Date function as such:
`dates<-c("2018-01", "2018-02", "2018-03", "2018-04", "2018-05", "2018-06", "2018-07", "2018-08", "2018-09", "2018-10", "2018-11", "2018-12", "2019-01", "2019-02", "2019-03", "2019-05", "2019-06", "2019-07", "2019-08", "2019-09", "2019-10", "2019-11", "2019-12", "2020-01", "2020-02")`

`dates <- as.Date(dates, format('%Y-%m'))`
However after I run this and check them the array has changed to this:
`[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
format(as.Date(paste0(dates, "-01")), "%Y-%m")
```